# Objective C - Watson Speech-To-Text API responds with 400 Bad Request error

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to get text response for my audio files (1 minute long duration).

My Code:

```
NSDictionary *headers = @{ @"authorization": @"Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXFpUG5YcA==",
                                   @"content-type": @"audio/wav",
                                   @"transfer-encoding": @"chunked" };

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?continuous=true&inactivity_timeout=-1"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

NSURLSessionUploadTask *task = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromFile:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
            NSUInteger responseStatusCode = [httpResponse statusCode];

            if(responseStatusCode == 200){
                callback(error,data);
            } else{
                [StaticClass showAlertWithTitle:@"Error" Message:@"Watson returned an error!"];
                NSError *err = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"Watson non-fatal issue" code:responseStatusCode userInfo:nil];
                [CrashlyticsKit recordError:err];
                callback(error,nil);
            }
        }];

[task resume];
```

This code gives proper response for more than 50% of the times.
But rest of the times, it gives a 400 Bad Request error:

```
{
    code = 400;
    "code_description" = "Bad Request";
    error = "unable to transcode data stream audio/wav -> audio/x-float-array ";
}
```

I'm using .wav files for uploading. 
Also, the error shows up only when the duration of file is more than a minute; for files with smaller duration the code works fine.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: hi Did you solve this?

Comment: Go through their documentation where the error codes are described. Check all possible causes. This was a long time ago and i think that my account has exceeded the free quota. But i'm not sure.